# How to determine which logstash instance running with python and jinja

Tags: python, logstash, jinja2

I was following this example
https://fabianlee.org/2016/10/31/python-using-python-json-and-jinja2-to-construct-a-set-of-logstash-filters/

I want to ask, when not using ansible template with the below command, we are able to run logstash instance

```
logstash -f path_to_config
```

But if we use ansible template with logstash, how should we determine which logstash instance running, I mean where should we store our logstash directories, and how should chose this instance in python.

Thanks for answering

Comment: I guess you must change the python code example, to put different output file in different directories and launch logstash instance with path_to_config corresponding of directory where desired output file was written.

Comment: Yes you are right. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is follow the

> https://fabianlee.org/2016/10/31/python-using-python-json-and-jinja2-to-construct-a-set-of-logstash-filters/

and put your py script in where you store logstash instance. Then run your py script for creating conf files and editing pipelines.yml, then just restart logstash service.